# Loops using Lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to create a for loop using lapply.
So basically, as and when the vector `columns_s` gets added, same vector gets created with its own value. For example, refer below

```
columns_s <- c("kingdom", "family")   ## user may add more elements to the vector
lapply(
  columns_to_consider,
  FUN = function(i){
   i = i
  })
```

Expected output

```
>kingdom
[1] "kingdom"

>family
[1] "family"
```

Comment: You may use `sapply` instead of `lapply`, with adding `simplify = FALSE` argument.

Comment: like, Can you show me the sample? :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `sapply`,

```
x <- sapply(
  c("kingdom", "family"),
  FUN = function(i){
    i = i
  }, simplify = F)
x
```

will give you result

```
$kingdom
[1] "kingdom"

$family
[1] "family"
```

Comment: Upvote but if the OP wants the input vector's *"own value"*, `sapply(columns_s, identity, simplify = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `*apply`:

```r
columns_s <- c("kingdom", "family")
as.list(setNames(nm = columns_s))
# $kingdom
# [1] "kingdom"
# $family
# [1] "family"
```